# The arithmetic product of quantum spins as a linear operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am reading Quantum Mechanics The Theoretical Minimum by Susskind and Friedman.

The authors set up a two spin system and two observables $\sigma_z$ and $\tau_z$ that measure the spin of of particles A and B respectively along the $z$ axis. They say at the bottom of page 177

> Let's suppose Alice measures $\sigma_z$ and Bob measures $\tau_z$, and
>   then they multiply the results. In other words, they conspire to
>   measure $\tau_z\sigma_z$. The product $\tau_z\sigma_z$ is an
>   observable that is mathematically represented by first applying
>   $\sigma_z$ to a ket and then subsequently applying $\tau_z$.

But I'm not seeing why the arithmetical product of the experiment outcome should represented by a composition of linear operators $\tau_z \circ \sigma_z$, except for maybe some urge (as of now unjustified) to replace $\circ$ by $\times$ and to reinterpret a linear operator as an experimental outcome.

Comment: Has the concept of direct products been discussed prior to this in the book?

Comment: They have mentioned tensor product, saying that $\sigma_z$ is actually $\sigma_z \times I$ and the basis is the pairwise concatenation of the single spin basis with itself